Intersection of a nowhere dense set with a dense set
Suppose that $A$ is nowhere dense and that $B$ is dense.
Is $A\cap B$ nowhere dense?
I think so, because $(A\cap B)\subseteq A$ and nowhere dense sets form an ideal of set. Is that correct?

Yes, any subset of a nowhere dense set is nowhere dense, basically by definition.

@DavidGao Thank you for your reply. So, on the other hand, $A\cup B$ is dense?

@LJGC yes, for similar reasons.

Just to ensure this has an answer. A set is dense provided its closure is the whole space. Thus any superset of a dense set is dense.
Then, nowhere dense means its intersection with any non-empty open set fails to be dense. Thus every subset of a nowhere dense set is nowhere dense, since every subset of a non-dense set fails to be dense by the above.
